# Finding User ID from Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623379/rails-tracking-a-users-id). Though I have not been able to figure it out yet. I want to be able to find the user id from the session. I understand that this can only be done within the controller, though I need this for a model method called Activity.log...

In my controller, I have the following:

```
@current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
user_id = @current_user.id
Activity.log(user_id)
```

I hope that I am at least on the right track, and from the other SO question I have linked to, I have assumed that sessions is still the best way to achieve this, though I am open to suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: `Activity.log( session[:user_id] )` does same thing?

Comment: A quick fix! That does work, although I am not sure why my original code (whilst being unnecessarily long) would not work still? Thanks though!

Comment: Could you post a log backtrace with an error ?

Comment: What actually is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @Bohdan, you may want to shorten your code a bit like this:

```
Activity.log( session[:user_id] )
```

In your case, you don't have to rely on ActiveRecord mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, this was the solution that I went with, thanks to Bohdan also.